# Why my own deb does not install /tmp/ files?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package

I created my own *.deb to install.
When i use :

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install <packageName>
```

**installation fails**, because required files in /tmp/ are missing.
However, when i display my *.deb content with :

```
dpkg -c <package>
```

I see all my /tmp/* files right here in my package.

**Why ./package.deb/tmp/* files are not copied to /tmp/* properly ?**

Comment: aptitude or dpkg appear to be in a blocked state, and refuse to execute installation properly. So the only one known solution is to do `sudo aptitude remove <package>` then `sudo aptitude install <package>`

Comment: Are you aware that normally the contents of /tmp are deleted after reboot?